# python script pauses, how to disable it?

Tags: python-2.7, output

I have a python script, to which I supply all the input once and then print some output. Now, what I expect is this format

```
            input 1
            input 2
            input 3
            output 1
            output 2
```

now my problem is when i run the python script, and supply the input (pasting it in the terminal) the output pauses after printing 'output 1' and i've to press enter to print it again.

```
from sets import Set

test_cases = int(raw_input())

while test_cases > 0:
    cats_vs_dogs = {}
    input_ = raw_input()
    input_ = input_.split(" ")
    total_cats = input_[0]
    total_dogs = input_[1]
    votes = int(input_[2])    
    remove_count = 0
    cats = Set()
    dogs = Set()
    for i in range(1, int(total_cats) + 1):
        cats.add('C' + str(i))
    for i in range(1, int(total_dogs) + 1):
        dogs.add('D' + str(i))

    for i in range(0, votes):
        input_ = raw_input()
        input_ = input_.split(" ")
        cat = input_[0]
        dog = input_[1]        
        if cat in cats:
            cats.remove(cat)
        elif cat in dogs:
            dogs.remove(cat)
        if dog in cats:
            cats.remove(dog)
        elif dog in dogs:
            dogs.remove(dog)

        if dog not in cats_vs_dogs:
            # now simply add the vote
            if cat in cats_vs_dogs:
                temp = list(cats_vs_dogs[cat])
                temp.append(dog)
                cats_vs_dogs[cat] = temp
            else:
                # cat was not found
                cats_vs_dogs[cat] = list([dog])
        else:
            # relevant dog is present, remove corresponding cat
            dogs_list = list(cats_vs_dogs[dog])
            if cat in dogs_list:
                # remove this entry and don't save it
                dogs_list.remove(cat)
                cats_vs_dogs[dog] = dogs_list
                remove_count += 1
            else:
                # no reverse entry exists so simply add
                if cat not in cats:
                    cats_vs_dogs[cat] = list([dog])
                else:
                    cats_list = list(cats_vs_dogs[cat])
                    cats_list.append(dog)
                    cats_vs_dogs[cat] = cats_list


    # now update the count
    for k in cats_vs_dogs.keys():
        remove_count += len(cats_vs_dogs[k])
    print remove_count + len(cats) + len(dogs)
    # print 'cats: ', cats
    # print 'dogs: ', dogs
    test_cases -= 1
    cats.clear()
    dogs.clear()
    cats_vs_dogs.clear()
```

what i supply as input is:

```
    2
    1 1 2
    C1 D1
    D1 C1
    1 2 4
    C1 D1
    C1 D1
    C1 D2
    D2 C1
```

output that i get is:

```
    ...
    D2 C11
    <system pause> I press enter
    3
```

whereas i want it to be as

```
    D2 C1<last line>
    1
    3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was trying to figure out what your code exactly does, but I can offer a few suggestions you might try:

- When you use `range()` you don't need to put in the zero, so `range(0,6)` is the same as `range (6)`.
- When you use `raw_input()` it is often helpful to include some kind of prompt. It's also helpful for debugging. This way you can tell if the pause you are seeing is actually waiting for input. An example would be `test_cases = raw_input("Enter number of test cases: ")`.
- Finally, as to your actual question: Your `print` statement is included in the `while` block. So it is probably printing something, then going back around to the entire code. Try pulling it out of the block and see what happens.